# What are some of the best missions to do on Grand Theft Auto 5 online

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

What are some of the best missions to do on Grand Theft Auto Online, like which missions will give you the most money/rp

Comment: Will you please quit correcting me

Comment: I'm trying to help you, dude.  This one is an automated comment that your question may have already been asked.  Arqade isn't a forum, and we like to ensure that questions that have been asked are all pointed at the same one, specifically so we don't have multiple questions, all asking the same thing, all with different answers.  One question, many answers, many readers, all in one place.

Comment: Alright, I understand that you are trying to help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the update, the two missions that would give you the highest amount of money and RP  were **Coveted ($18,000/1450 RP)** and **Rooftop Rumble ($18,750/3275 RP)**

**Hack and Dash ($12,000–$24,000/1520 RP)**, as well as **Chemical Extraction ($15,000-$30,000/3850 RP)** are other good jobs, but you have to work together as a team. The previous two jobs are easy to do by yourself. Note, these amounts are on the Hard difficulty, which means you just can't go Rambo in the missions and think you'll pass it.

As for the new missions (5/13/14) I haven't played them yet, but once I do, I'll update my answer.

This might be a helpful resource: http://gta.wikia.com/Missions_in_GTA_Online

Comment: Thanks a lot @kameOVER, that's useful info, and yes please update ASAP... Thank You